# Compute from another component VueJs

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component, which holds unit price, quantity and would like to compute a grand total in the view which is not inside the component. What can I do to achieve that?
Each component is dynamically generated, here's a sample code.
Thanks!

```
<table>
<tr is="item-grid" v-for='index in counter'></tr>
<tr><td v-text="sub_total"></td></tr>
<button @click="counter++" type="button">TEST ADD ROW</button>
</table>


<template id="item-template">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="inventory_name" readonly/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="sku"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="qty"/></td>
        <td><input v-model="unit_price"></input></td>
        <td><span v-text="unit_total"></span></td>
        <td><button @click="remove(this)" type="button">delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</template>


<script>

    var Item = {
        template: '#item-template',

        data: function(){
            return {'qty': 0, 'unit_price': 0.00, 'inventory_name': '', 'sku': ''}
        },

        methods:{
            remove: function(a){
                console.log(a);
            }
        },

        computed: {
            unit_total: function(){
                return this.qty * this.unit_price;
            }
        }

    }

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        props: ['item','sub_total','tax','grand_total'],

        data: {
            'counter': 1,
        },

        components: {
            'item-grid': Item,
        },

        // computed: {
        //     sub_total: function(){
        //         return Item.unit_total++;
        //     }
        // }


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to keep the values that will be used for computation in external object, and then use them from that object in place where you need to do computation.

Comment: @BelminBedak  All the components are dynamically generated, is it possible to re-loop them to compute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this, I added only computed part, you can edit in fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rdjjpc7a/3003/

```js
var Item = {
        template: '#item-template',

        data: function(){
            return {
             item_rows:[{'qty': 0, 'unit_price': 0.00, 'inventory_name': '', 'sku': ''}]
            }
        },

        methods:{
            remove: function(index){
              if (index > -1) {
           this.item_rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
                console.log(item);
            },
            add:function(){
             this.item_rows.push({'qty': 0, 'unit_price': 0.00, 'inventory_name': '', 'sku': ''});
            }
        },

        computed: {
            unit_total: function(){
                return this.qty * this.unit_price;
            },
            sub_total: function(){
                 var subTotal=0;
                 this.item_rows.map(function(item){
                    if(item.qty>0 && item.unit_price > 0){
                    subTotal += item.qty*item.unit_price;
                    }
                 });
                 return subTotal;
            }
            
        }

    }

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        props: ['item','sub_total','tax','grand_total'],

        data: {
            'counter': 1,
        },

        components: {
            'item-grid': Item,
        },

        // computed: {
        //     sub_total: function(){
        //         return Item.unit_total++;
        //     }
        // }


    });
```

```css
input{
  width : 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<item-grid></item-grid>
</div>
<template id="item-template">
    <table>
    <tr v-for="(item,index) in item_rows">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.inventory_name" readonly/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.sku"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.qty"/></td>
        <td><input v-model="item.unit_price"></td>
        <td><span v-text="item.qty*item.unit_price"></span></td>
        <td><button @click="remove(index)" type="button">delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><button @click="add" type="button">Add Row</button></td><td colspan="3">Sub Total : {{sub_total}}</td></tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

Comment: I think you have mistaken my question, i would want to compute sub_total...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but using a global event bus may be helpful in such situations.

> The event bus / publish-subscribe pattern, despite the bad press it sometimes gets, is still an excellent way of getting unrelated sections of your application to talk to each other.

Here's the [article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)